# Pass a value from a URL into a Drop Down List using Javascript

Tags: javascript

I have a url as follows

```
http://*****************?ContentId=1335&clientName=Sam&clientPhone=123&clientEmail=an@gmail.com&clientCountry=United%20Kingdom.
```

clientCountry is a name of a drop down list in my form and I want to pass the value (United Kingdom) into that drop down list using Javascript.

I have been able to do this so far

```
function getUrlVars()
{
var vars = [], hash;
var hashes = window.location.href.slice(window.location.href.indexOf('?') +    1).split('&');
for(var i = 0; i < hashes.length; i++)
{
hash = hashes[i].split('=');
vars.push(hash[0]);
vars[hash[0]] = hash[1];
}
return vars;
}
var first = getUrlVars()["clientName"];
var second = getUrlVars()["clientPhone"];
var third = getUrlVars()["clientEmail"];
var fourth = getUrlVars()["clientCountry"];
```

Now I do not know how to pass the variable fourth into the drop down list. Can anyone assist as I am a total novice with javascript?

Comment: Do you want to preselect a value in an existing dropdown list based on the URL parameter?

Comment: yes that is correct, the url carrying the data needs to populate a form.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have already populated the dropdown list, this should work for preselecting the value from the URL:

```
var dropDowns = document.getElementsByTagName('select'), opts, i;
for(i = 0, l=dropDowns.length;i<l;++i){
  if(dropDowns[i].name === 'countryList'){
    opts = dropDowns[i].getElementsByTagName('option');
    for(i = 0, l = opts.length;i<l;++i){
      if(opts[i].value === fourth){
        opts[i].selected = true;
        break;
      }
    }
    break;
  }
}
```

Make sure this runs after you print the markup for the select by binding to the document ready event, or include it somewhere in the page after you print the markup for the dropdown list. It uses the *fourth* variable from the code you included, so that should have run when you run this.